# Can't swipe a `UIPageViewController` with a `UINavigationController`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I've got an app with a `UIPageViewController` that is set up like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCNavController"];
self.navViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, nil];

self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainPageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

if ([self.navViewControllers count] != 0)
{
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[self.navViewControllers[0]]
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I've implemented all the necessary delegate functions and my `MainViewController` that is hosting the `UIPageViewController` is conforming to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`.

**Hierarchy**

- `MainViewController`

  - `UIPageViewController`

    - `UINavigationController`

      - `UIViewController`

The last `UIViewController` in my hierarchy is displayed correctly, however, I cannot swipe the `UIPageViewController`. **Is there an obvious reason I haven't accounted for?** I'm thinking perhaps the `UINavigationController` doesn't work all that well with the delegate functions supplied by the delegate/datasource, or that the `UINavigationController` interferes with the touches. Nevertheless, I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would need the `UINavigationController`, is there a specific reason for this? Try removing the `UINavigationController` and adding the `UIViewControllers` directly to the `UIPageViewController`. Then handle `UIGestures` in the `UIPageViewController`. This should achieve the desired effect if I understood you correctly.

Comment: I have a feeling that it would fix it, as I've done that before - but I want the UINavigationBar in only one of the UIViewControllers

Comment: I think the only way you'll manage that is by letting that UIViewController mimic a UINavigationController. Since the UINavigationController is meant to stay constant and manage navigation through a data type model application, so that might be causing the issue. You could check this by inserting UIViewControllers and in the middle a UINavigationController. If swipe works until the UINavigationController is displayed, that is the issue and you would then need to mimic. I hope this helps and makes sense.

Comment: I did a little experimenting with this by adding a few extra `UIViewControllers` as you suggested. It worked then, but I realised I didn't change the scroll animation from page curl to scroll, so that animations weren't correct either. I changed it to swipe, and apparently that made swiping on `UINavigationController` work as well!

Comment: Alright perfect! Also good info for me for future reference :) I'm glad I could help :)